# How to save on disk the module resulting from AssemblyBuilder since dotnet 5?

Tags: .net, .net-5, reflection.emit

The following example is outdated for dotnet 5.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder?view=net-5.0#examples

Even with the query-string containing `?view=net-5.0` that example does not compile successfully. I have already updated some of those obsolete features to the new API.

Yet, I still need to save the resulting module (DLL) to check the IL through the PEVerify or IL Verifier.

So, what is the replacement for the absent `Save()` method of `AssemblyBuilder`?

---

For now my workaround is to replace `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>` by `<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>` in `.csproj`, but that is a completely mess.

Moreover, although `dotnet` command line tool forbid the use of `-f net48`, we can still change it by hand in the `.csproj` and get a correct project.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you can't, as that functionality [is not yet implemented in .NET Core/.NET 5.0 and probably won't be in .NET 6.0 either](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15704#issuecomment-732330853).

Until or unless said functionality is implemented in .NET, [ILPack](https://github.com/Lokad/ILPack) should do what you require.

Regarding the broken examples, I have [opened an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/23983).